# ODS ESCAPECHAR not working in ODS TEXT output in SAS EG

Tags: sas

I'm creating a PDF report with multiple sections using the ODS LAYOUT statement and am frustrated with the lack of options for inserting text into the document.

I've searched all day on the internet for how to format the text from the ODS TEXT or ODS PDF TEXT statements and the most common solution seems to be to use the ODS ESCAPECHAR statement to insert style options.

However, when I write even a very simple code like the following:

```
ods escapechar="^";
ods pdf file="\filelocation\hello.pdf";
ods text="1. Normal Text";
ods text="^S={FONT_SIZE=18pt FONT_WEIGHT=bold JUST=c} 2. Modified Text";
```

I get the following output in my PDF file:

> 1. Normal Text
>
> ^S={FONT_SIZE=18pt FONT_WEIGHT=bold JUST=c} 2. Modified Text

I've spent most of the day reading the documentation and have tried this many ways from many different tutorials, including replacing the character, replacing the bracket types, replacing double quotes with single quotes, replacing S with STYLE=, etc. None of these seem to work.

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1

Comment: Works fine on my side... have you tried using the default escape sequence `(*ESC*)` instead of  `^`?

Comment: It actually worked fine once I restarted my SAS session and I haven't had an issue since, so I'm not sure what the problem was or what caused it.